# Airflow DAG schedule based from database table

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Currently, I have DAGs where schedule interval are defined in the DAG itself. I think I can use airflow variables for this also. Instead of variables I thought of creating a database table to store the values and use PostgresHook(or other db hooks) to pull data from table to populate the schedule_interval, start_date or default_args of DAGs. So just wondering if this is efficient/possible. I just thought that this might result to large unnecessary queries on the airflow database.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to _why_ this is something you're looking to do?

Comment: The values for default_args, schedule_interval, etc is something that we want to be managed by users of different env (prod, stage, qa, or dev). So having a database table to do that might be feasible but I think this will be inefficient and might result to airflow db connection issues.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `schedule_interval` can be hairy, especially if you have sensors that check for prior run success or `wait_for_downstream` set; anything that introspects the state of the database by `execution_date` really.

It *could* work and you could likely piggy-back on the `models.Variable` table but you'll have to deal with the increased database load, increased load time for your webserver, the scheduler will be slower and now doing any local testing/development requires that you now sync the databases.

We use a version controlled repository with multiple branches to keep code separated which also helps to enforce a peer review of code prior to being pushed to Airflow.

Comment: That's what I thought too but wanted to double-check before going down this path. Thanks for the input.

Comment: It will work - but dynamically changing schedules is a very bad idea in airflow.